# Middleware calls next but program still hangs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, middleware

I wrote some simple middleware to add something to the request object on each request. No matter which path the flow takes at some point next should be called, however the response never does and so all my routes which are defined after it are unreachable. Is there something wrong with  my code?

The middleware is:

```
module.exports = (db) => {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        if(req.isAuthenticated()){
            debugger;
            db.user.findOne({where:{id:req.user.id}})
                .then((user)=>{
                    //set user permission
                    if(user.permission_id === 1){
                        //user is an Client
                        req.userIdentity = 'client';
                    }else if(user.permission_id === 2){
                        //user is a Coach
                        req.userIdentity = 'coach';
                    }else if(user.permission_id === 3){
                        //user is Admin
                        req.userIdentity = 'admin';
                    }

                    //set user status
                    if(user.user_status_id === 1){
                        req.userStatus = 'active';
                    }else if(user.user_status_id === 2){
                        req.userStatus = 'inactive';
                    }else if(user.user_status_id === 3){
                        req.userStatus = 'pending';
                    }

                    next();
                });
        }
        else{
            return next();
        }
    }
};
```

I call it like this in app.js:

```
 app.use(passport.initialize());
 app.use(passport.session());
require('./services/passport');

//get identity of user. ie client, coach, or admin
const userIdentity =require('./services/userIdentity');
app.use(userIdentity(db)); <====== this is the middleware

//initiate route handlers
app.use('/login', require('./routes/authRoutes'));
app.use('/tiles', require('./routes/tileRoutes'));
app.use('/user-info', require('./routes/userRoutes'));

//this path MUST stay below other route handlers
app.get('*', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './client/build/index.html'));
});
```

UPDATE****
added `.catch(err=>res.send(err));`
to see if that was it, but it's not. I used the debugger statement to step through the code and the database call is definitely returning what it should. My if/elses all get stepped through as appropriate and then nothing, the app just stops.

Comment: I guess the problem is the query you are doing to database, because you are implementing just the happy flow, using the promise .then function but you are not implementing a catch function to check for errors, so, the request maybe is in the error flow. Check it :))

Comment: I'm with @JoseMato , are you sure there is no error, as that will of course cause another flow that doesn't reach next.  Currently in node if you have an unhandled promise exception, it will appear in the console.  You not seeing anything here?

Comment: You are not handling errors from `db.user.findOne()`.  So, if the promise rejects, you do nothing and `next()` is never called.  You need a `.catch()`.